# Which design pattern for logging user activity

Tags: design-patterns

I need to log some aspects of the user's activity. Basically the update, insert and delete to some tables. It is a php based web application. This means no Aspect Oriented Programming.

I would like to have your suggestions about the most adequate design pattern to use in this situation.

Thanks

Comment: A design pattern? What's wrong with plain old logging? You are trying to apply too-sophisticated terms to a trivial problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design pattern isn't quite the term you want. You basically mean "thing people do a lot to solve this problem."

Semantics aside, while there is no standard AOP support, you can use the Go! library to achieve AOP with PHP. Here is an [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/aspect-oriented-programming-in-php-with-go/) on using Go! for logging.

You have other choices as well like [Flow](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/aspect-oriented-programming-in-php-with-go/) and within [Lithium](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium).

Comment: More information is available on official site of Go! AOP, for example, [aspect-oriented logging in PHP with doctrine annotations](http://go.aopphp.com/blog/2013/07/21/implementing-logging-aspect-with-doctrine-annotations/)

Answer (score 0):

If you place this in php code, you'll have to duplicate the logic if you ever want to use some other language.

Your simplest option might be to simply use triggers in your database (no design patterns required!)

But then if you place this logic in your database you'll have to find an alternative should you ever want to move to a different data store.

With injected logging at the code level you'll be able to log more than just SQL CRUD ops, if you need that? With triggers you won't have to worry about transactions and atomicty.

I think it comes down to the specifics of your requirements and how much time you can afford to spend on it more than an idealistic application of design patterns. I would encourage pragmatism!